# Trigger a jQuery function on load

Tags: jquery

I have this code to make a div a slid open and close, the problem is I want it to default to open.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.slider').each(function () {
        var current = $(this);
        current.attr("box_h", current.height());
    });
    $(".slider").css("height", sliderHeight);
    $(".slider_menu").html('<a href="javascript:void(0)">More <img src="images/more_down.gif" border="0"></a>');
    $(".slider_menu a").click(function () {
        openSlider()
    });
});

function openSlider() {
    var open_height = $(".slider").attr("box_h") + "px";
    $(".slider").animate({
        "height": open_height
    }, {
        duration: "slow"
    });

    $(".slider_menu").html('<a href="javascript:void(0)">Close <img src="images/more_up.gif" border="0"></a>');
    $(".slider_menu a").click(function () {
        closeSlider()
    })
};

function closeSlider() {
    $(".slider").animate({
        "height": sliderHeight
    }, {
        duration: "slow"
    });

    $(".slider_menu").html('<a href="javascript:void(0)">More <img src="images/more_down.gif" border="0"></a>');
    $(".slider_menu a").click(function () {
        openSlider()
    })
};
```

how can i trigger it to open once the page is loaded?

Comment: Is there a reason you didn't use .slideToggle() instead of your hand-crafted openSlider and closeSlider?

Answer (score 0):

Try `window.onload = openSlider;`

Answer (score 0):

Just call `openSlider()` in the `document.ready`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.slider').each(function () {
                var current = $(this);
                current.attr("box_h", current.height());});     
    $(".slider").css("height", sliderHeight);
    $(".slider_menu").html('<a href="javascript:void(0)">More <img src="images/more_down.gif" border="0"></a>');
    $(".slider_menu a").click(function() { openSlider() });    
    openSlider();      
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add it to you ready function:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.slider').each(function () {
                var current = $(this);
                current.attr("box_h", current.height());});     
    $(".slider").css("height", sliderHeight);
    $(".slider_menu").html('<a href="javascript:void(0)">More <img src="images/more_down.gif" border="0"></a>');
    $(".slider_menu a").click(function() { openSlider() });         
    openSlider();  // <---------here
});
```

if you can do without the animation you can just set the default CSS to have it open.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".slider_menu a").click(function() { closeSlider() })
```

that adds the handler

```
$(".slider_menu a").click()
```

that triggers the event.
In your case you might as well call openSlider like guys above suggested but I've entered the trigger example so you might know in the future that click can be used in two way.

It doesn't make sense to change dynamically html in you'r code like you do. But if you want to stick to this solution for whatever reason first call unbind on the 'a' before you recreate html otherwise you might have memory leaks.

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you simply just call your function openSlider in the $(document).ready ?!